# Why does the Ubuntu Dock lose track of my Chromium window?

Tags: gnome, chromium

When I have a Chromium window open for a while, GNOME and/or just the Ubuntu dock loses track of it. Note in the screenshot how I have a window open but there is no orange dot next to Chromium on the sidebar. I can still interact with the window with the mouse, I can still <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to it, but I cannot navigate to it with a click on the Chromium icon on the sidebar or using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (as it is on the top of the list), both of these actions open a new window as if it isn't currently running.

As on September 24, 2020, I was using Ubuntu 19.10 and GNOME Shell 3.34.1. But then later on, I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm still experiencing this issue.

[image]

Comment: Does this issue happen with any other app?

Comment: I've only noticed it with chromium, and it doesn't happen immediately. I have a hunch it might be related to when memory gets low and/or laptop sleep/suspend, but I haven't figured out a consistent repro.

Comment: Which version of Chromium are you using? Is it the latest version? What are the steps you followed to install Chromium?

Comment: BTW, what is the GNOME version which you have right now?

Comment: Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

GNOME Shell 3.36.4

I believe that I installed it though the Ubuntu Software Center, here is how it reports there (although I know you can also install outside debs though the center too, so it's possible I did that).

Channel: latest/stable,
Version: 85.0.4183.121,
Developer: Canonical,
Source: snapcraft.io

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the app and check if the issue persists?

Comment: I've noticed this as well with other apps, not just Chromium, such as Slack and VS Code.

Comment: I'm curious if the devs on the affected project would like to have a repro of the issue, even if a reinstall might fix it. I'm not sure if it's GNOME itself or just the ubuntu doc. @Zanna what was the reason for removing the ubuntu dock tags that had been added?

Comment: Probably just a mistake on my part - feel free to add them back if they are correct

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/910

It looks like this has been reported to the dash-to-dock project and is still open.

Thought it would be worthwhile to at least post the quick workaround mentioned in that github issue here until the devs can address the issue.

"Only way I've found to solve it when it happens is to do an "alt+f2" and type the "r" and enter to reload the entire gnome-shell."

Comment: I've also run into this issue.  It also happens with Atom which is based on Chromium.  Have you found resolution in the last few months?

Comment: @JimmyJames Nope, unfortunately I'm still using this workaround.

Comment: I"m having this same problem with chrome and vscode but the your work around doesn't help.